# How partial download works in HTTP/2?

Tags: http

HTTP/2 is good for downloading multiple resources, as it supports multiplexing. 
I am currently using HTTP/1.1 and we use range based download (multiple partial downloads) using range header.

We created multiple connections for download.

We are planning to move on HTTP/2, does multiplexing help here, can we download all the partial chunks in the single connection?

In short my question is,

In HTTP/2 I can get multiple resources like .html, .css,.js, etc in one connection. For the same, I need to use different connections in HTTP/1.1. Now when I download range based, in HTTP/1.1 it created multiple connections for each part, in HTTP/2 all the parts of a single file will be downloaded in one connection. Is that correct?

Comment: What are you aiming at? Performance? Multiple connections will always be at least as fast, and most likely faster. For starters you can connect to multiple physical servers. Other then that if you have working solution then what is the point of change?

Comment: @freakish Performance is a concern. I am trying to figure out if partial download using range-based headers is possible in HTTP/2. I have searched for this on the internet but didn't get anything related to multiplexing and range based headers for download.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that multiple connections actually speed up things (which in general should not be the case, unless there's packet loss or throtteling), then you'll have to do the same in HTTP/2 (HTTP/2 multiplexing uses a single TCP connection).

Comment: So you mean to say, I can use range based headers to download multiple chunks of the file using multiplexing?

Comment: You can do the same thing as in HTTP/1.1. One one or multiple TCP connection. It should just not make any difference, unless a single connection is throttled, in which case you'd be working around an intentional server limit. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: In HTTP/2 I can get multiple resources like .html, .css,.js, etc in one connection. For the same, I need to use different connections in HTTP/1.1. Now when I download range based, in HTTP/1.1 it created multiple connections for each part, in HTTP/2 all the parts of a single file will be downloaded in one connection. Is that correct?

Comment: In HTTP/1.1, you don't *need* multiple connections. You can keep the connection open and just fire the requests one-by-one. The difference in HTTP/2 is only that within a single connection you can have multiple requests/responses at once in parallel. That doesn't mean you habe to use a single connection.

Comment: Yes that is the purpose, I don't want multiple connections should open. I want single connections and parallel request for single file that I will partially download.